# How to retrieve data from input form using body.req in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, ejs

I am pretty new into coding. I am coding a tiny CRUD, where I try to find how to search an element using its ID on my previously created mySQL DB, thing is I made another method to show messages using an ID on the route, writing it manually in the browser URL place, however, I want to do use a POST form.The one I use to get via url looks like this...

That's the route in my router.

```
router.get('/search/:id', messageController.getMessageById);
```

and this is is the method.

```
  exports.getMessageById = (req, res, next) => {
  const MessageId = req.params.id;
  Message.selectById(MessageId).then(([message])=>{
    res.render('editmessage',{
      message: message[0]
    });
  }).catch(err => console.log(err)); 

};
```

That code above is in my controller.

I got an .ejs view with a form, what I actually want is to take the data from the input

```
<div>

  <form method="post" action="/search/:id">
    <input type="text" name="id"> 
    <p>write your id.</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</div>
```

So... How can I take the id written in the input form and then redirect the client dinamically to the message?

For example, writting 45 on the input form, to redirect it to http://message/45

(

it will show another view with a

element which will contain the body message of message #45 in my db

)

Thanks in advance!

[Crud at github](https://github.com/IDymov-s/APNT)

Comment: What's `:id` in the view? That won't magically change to the id the user enters. I think you're looking for the route to be `/search` and then you can access the GET params like `req.query.id` if you change to `POST` on the form and route then use `req.body.id`

Comment: also router.get should be router.post if your POSTing from the form.

Comment: also on error you would want to use next() or respond with something else the page will hang